# Network sniffer in Python

Tags: python, tcpdump, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I'm trying to find a good and stable network packet sniffer in python, that allows me to do exactly the as I used to with `tcpdump`.

I found this `pycap` but it does not seem to be that stable... Another options would be `Scapy` but it does not handle reassembling TCP streams.

Any other options? Or am I wrong about `pycap`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're worried about the stability of other python based packages, you can use python's `ctypes` library to dynamically load in `libpcap.so`.

You can find out more on using `libpcap.so` [over here](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html) while the ctypes documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html).

Comment: I actually ended up using pycap since PyShark was not what I expected. Pycap uses libpcap and libnet so I should be fine with it. I'd like to do it the easy and quick way. That's why I did not use ctypes. But thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [PyShark](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshark/0.2). It allows you to sniff specific interface continuously.

Comment: wow. PyShark is incredibly bad! no documentation at all!